# What was “Herbal Tea” called before ‘tea’ was introduced in Europe?

Tags: etymology, synonyms

I recently got in a discussion with a colleague, about *herbal tea* not being a correct term, as it contains no *tea*. Instead, one ought to use the term *herbal infusions*.

Tea (dried leaves from the tea plant aka *Camellia sinensis*) was gradually introduced in Europe during the 16th/17th century, but the making of herbal teas — all right, herbal *infusions* — was already widespread at the time.

So, my question: How did they call these herbal infusions? The term *infusion* sounds very scientific to me, so was there another way these were referred to?

Comment: I know that e.g. in Spanish the term *infusion* is everyday usage and far from "very scientific".

Comment: Incidentally, a lot of modern herbal teas do actually contain some amount of tea.

Comment: It seems to have very quickly been applied to infusion of non-tea plants (New Jersey Tea etc). One wonders how many hundreds of years is needed until your friend accepts a minor broadening of word usage.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Tisane.

> an infusion (as of dried herbs) used as a beverage or for medicinal effects
>
> Middle English, from Anglo-French, from Latin ptisana, from Greek
> ptisanē, literally, crushed barley, from ptissein to crush — more at
> pestle
> First Known Use: 14th century

[dictionary.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tisane)

edit: Tim Romano's answer below is superior to mine.

Comment: Interesting! For some reason, I always associated the first part of *tisane* with "tea," but it looks like they have entirely different origins.

Comment: Also worth noting that a tisane made from a single herb intended to be medicinal may also be known as a *simple*.

Comment: http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=215142735&egdisplay=open&egs=215146767

Comment: I'm with @sumelic. Learn something new each day.

Comment: [Hercule Poirot approves](http://agathaportal.blogspot.co.uk/2007/01/poirots-favourite-drinks.html)

Comment: And of course, before the introduction of hops into the brewing process in the 15th century, an "iced tisane" was more commonly known as any of beer, lager, ale, or pilsner, depending on country of residence. ;-)

Comment: It is incorrect to call an herb based drink a tea. A tea must come from the tea plant. The correct term is an infusion.

Comment: @sergiol: Who is that comment addressed to?

Comment: @sumelic: To everybody. Comments are not forcibly unidirectional.

Comment: @sergiol So who called it a tea?

Answer (score 62):

> So, my question: How did they call these herbal infusions?

During the Middle English period, the concoction made from the herb was itself referred to as an herb. They would say "Drink this herb".

They didn't bother to say "infusion of this herb".

> Drinke þis herbe..and it [wol] make al þe body in-to a swat.

*A Middle English Translation of Macer Floridus de Viribus Herbarum*, ed. G. Frisk

Comment: I'd love to accept your answer as well, because @Chris and your answer complement each other. Unfortunately , this is one of the limitations of StackExchange. So let me just say: Thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, and you're welcome. But take note that during the Middle English period, **tisane**  was, per the MED, "a medicinal drink made from shelled barley and water", not a general term for "infusion".  *Of bareliche yscheled and ysoden in water is medicynable drynk ymade þat phisicians clepiþ thisane.* A medicinal drink that physicians call **thisane** is made of shelled barley soaked in water.

Comment: First time I've actually seen the letter thorn put to use. Or should that be þorn?

Comment: Can you give more reference besides this one quotation?  This seems very appealing and plausible, but none of the dictionaries I’ve checked (including the OED and MED) mention this usage of *herb* — i.e. they list various senses, including “a medicinal plant…” or similar, but they do not list anything like “…an infusion prepared from such plants”.

Comment: @Pharap - Oh, you've seen it all the time, it just gets bastardized into a 'y' most of the time.  E.g. "Ye Olde Taverne" or whatnot (should be "Þe Olde Taverne", or as we would read it "The Olde Taverne"), because the old English script for a 'þ' looks a lot like a backwards 'y'.

Comment: @Pharap: not surprising you’re seeing it online — you know, the internet is for þorn.

Comment: @PLL: Oh my, I dread what happens when the spammers discover Unicode...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Oddly enough I've never actually seen a 'Ye olde' anything outside in the context of film and television, where it exists as a trope.

Comment: @PLL: In the MED there's no entry for the noun **herbe** with the definition "an herbal infusion".  They did use the word **infusion** but I see no attestation for "infusion of herbes". There are several attestations for "drink this herb". That could be ellipsis, where they simply don't state the obvious, since leaves cannot be drunk; or it could be that the word **herb** referred to the plant, its leaves, and the beverage produced therefrom.

Comment: @Pharap, pubs and tea shops in rural England. Almost unheard of anywhere else.

Comment: @Separatrix I live in the west of England and I've never seen one. Evidently I must be visiting the wrong places.

Answer (score 13):

When you boil down the question, the appropriate answer hinges on what would have been meant by "herbal tea" prior to the introduction of the word 'tea' in the sense of

> **2. a.** A drink made by infusing these [*Thea* (now often included in *Camellia*)] leaves in hot water, having a somewhat bitter and aromatic flavour, and acting as a moderate stimulant; largely used as a beverage.

["tea, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/198340?rskey=tnWhke&result=1&isAdvanced=false (accessed April 30, 2016).]

The word in forms resembling modern 'tea', and used in sense **2.a**, that is, the drink as opposed to the plant, is not attested in *OED Online* until the mid-1600s (**1658**, 'Tcha', 'Tay', 'Tee'), earlier attested forms in English being 'Chia' and 'cha'.

If a meaning approximating what is encompassed by 'herbal infusion', that is, a specific process-oriented meaning, is intended, 'infusion' is not attested in that sense until, at the earliest, the mid-1500s (**?1550**). Note that uses of 'infusion' with that meaning refer to *medicinal* preparations made by steeping as opposed to boiling.

> **4. b.** A dilute liquid extract obtained from a substance by soaking it with, or steeping it in, water; also any water containing dissolved organic (esp. vegetable) matter, such as that in which *Infusoria* are found.

["infusion, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/95690 (accessed April 30, 2016).]

Another specific process-oriented word might be 'decoction'. It is attested in **1398** in this sense:

> **4.** A liquor in which a substance, usually animal or vegetable, has been boiled, and in which the principles thus extracted are dissolved; *spec.* as a medicinal agent.

["decoction, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/48312 (accessed April 30, 2016).]

As with 'infusion', 'decoction' was used with reference to specifically *medicinal* prepartions. As opposed to the steeping denoted by 'infusion', 'decoction' denotes boiling to obtain the preparation.

My nomination for the appropriate word to answer *your particular question* departs from *process-oriented* meanings in favor of a *purpose-oriented* meaning. The word was in use much earlier, but the evidence, its attestation from **c1220-c1440**, suggests it was perhaps obsoleted by the process-oriented words 'infusion' and 'decoction' in literate if not in common use prior to the introduction of 'tea':

> † **halewei | halewey**, *n.*
>   *Obs.*
>   A healing water, used both as a drink, and as a lotion for wounds; balm, antidote.

["† halewei | halewey, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/83398 (accessed April 30, 2016).]

Other authorities tend to cast 'halewey' as a particular kind of tea, rather than a generic term (healing water), although they differ on its composition:

[image: halewey1]

(From [*Totally Weird and Wonderful Words*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5M0bKNbSgPcC&pg=PA82&dq=halewey&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJt4zDl7jMAhVD2WMKHV3mAmYQ6AEISTAI#v=onepage&q=halewey&f=false), Erin McKean, Oxford University Press, Oct 23, 2006).

[image: halewey2]

(From [*Selections from Early Middle English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=wcgzAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA623&dq=halewei&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0yZyWnrjMAhUY2GMKHUxgAlg4KBDoAQgsMAM#v=onepage&q=halewei&f=false), Joseph Hall, Clarendon Press, 1920.)

Another good candidate than 'halewey', attested from before 1200 with documentary evidence dated around 1225 (dates uncertain), has a generic process-oriented meaning alternative to the purpose-oriented meaning of 'halewey':

> † **sabras**, *n.*
>   *Obs.*
>   A decoction or infusion.
>   ?c1225  (▸?a1200)    *Ancrene Riwle* (Cleo. C.vi) (1972) 268   Þe an for geað alþet he luued. of metes & of drunches. & drinkeð bittere sabraz forto acouren heale.

["† sabras, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/169377 (accessed May 01, 2016).]

As little is known about the composition of 'sabras' (variant 'sabrace') as about the composition of 'halewey', but it has been suggested that the word derives from an Arabic word for 'a drink':

> In the *Ancren Riwle*, edited for the Camden Society by the Rev. J. Morton, p. 364, it is said that a sick man who is wise uses abstinence, and drinks bitter sabras to recover his health: in the Latin MS. Oxon. *potat amara*. It may be from the Arabic, "Shabra, a drink." See *Notes and Queries*, vol. ii. pp. 70, 204.

(From [*Promptorium Parvulorum Sive Clericorum: Dictionarius Anglo-Latinum Princeps*](https://books.google.com/books?id=BcUMAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA440&dq=sabras&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiboKKEmLjMAhUM72MKHb47ArYQ6AEIXTAI#v=onepage&q=sabras&f=false), Volume 89, Sumptibus Societatis Camdenensis. This is an 1865 edition of the *Promptorium Parvulorum*, itself dated around 1440, edited and annotated by Albertus Way.)

Answer (score -2):

My wife did a tour at Celestial Seasonings. According to the tour guide, *herbal infusions* is what they originally called their products, but they didn't sell very well until they changed the name to *herbal tea*.

Comment: Unless that company is several hundred years old (which they aren't), this anecdote does not answer the question.

Comment: Perhaps not the company itself, but I imagine they didn't invent the practice, or the terminology.